# Pass code using POST method

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I made a form that receives source code that can be written in C/C++/Python/Java/Ruby

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $problem_code=$_GET['id'];
    echo '<form name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/result-board.php?id='.$problem_code.'" method="post">';
}
?>
<textarea id="editor" class="editor" rows="25" cols="100" name="code">
</textarea>
<select id="lang" name="lang" class="lang">
<option value="11" selected>C</option>
<option value="41">C++</option>
<option value="4">Python 2</option>
<option value="116">Python 3</option>
<option value="55">Java</option>
<option value="17">Ruby</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is the code for result-board.php

```
<?php
include "conn_db.php";
$code=stripcslashes($_POST['code']);
$lang= stripcslashes($_POST['lang']);
echo $code.$lang;
?>
```

What should I use in case of POST method so that correct data can be receive.

Comment: You did't put your full form code (missing <form> tag)

Comment: that is there with his echo statement.

Comment: you also mixed rank-board.php with result-board.php

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch sorry post edited now

Answer (score 0):

your form should be something like: 
`<form name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/result-board.php' method="post">`

and then add your problem code like,

`<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $problem_code;?>" name="code"/>`

and then access with your name like,

$_POST['code']

Comment: @isssueNo329 i have a code-editor in which code will be pasted or will be written so can't use hidden method but how ecntype="multipart/form-data" can help ?

Comment: ok if you are ok then use visible field itself and You can get values with your html name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $problem_code=$_GET['id'];
    }else{
        $problem_code=0;
    }

    echo '<form name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/result-board.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$problem_code.'" name="id"/>';

    ?>
<textarea id="editor" class="editor" rows="25" cols="100" name="code"></textarea>
<select id="lang" name="lang" class="lang">
<option value="11" selected>C</option>
<option value="41">C++</option>
<option value="4">Python 2</option>
<option value="116">Python 3</option>
<option value="55">Java</option>
<option value="17">Ruby</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that was not the problem code working fine but the content of $_POST['code'] are not same means they broke up even not printing the whole code submiited via form